# Wordpress Slideshow Gallery in Post with Description

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gallery, slideshow

im looking for a slideshow gallery pluggin for wordpress exactly like this:

http://www.brides.com/wedding-ideas/wedding-style/2011/06/rainbow-wedding-color-scheme-rainbow-wedding#slide=1

İmages with descriptions and thumbnails. How can i do that or do you know pluggin like this?

Thank you...